# Accessing CSV data from raw github file using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Why does the following code give the error?:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

url= 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/drinks.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(url)
```

Comment: I do not get an error when I run this exact code. I would suggest that perhaps you have not used the correct web address. Also, maybe the link was offline when you checked? Try again.

Comment: As mentioned by @edesz, I have tried to run your code with python 3.7.1 and pandas 0.23 and there is no error.

Comment: hmmm. Thanks guys, maybe it's because I'm using my company computer and security features prevent using urllib?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not connected through a proxy or VPN.

I had this same issue while working from home while connected to my company's VPN. As soon as I disconnected from VPN the error went away.